# How to configure the path to the pdflatex and Ghostscript executables manually

Tags: latex, matex

There is a [blog post](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) for a detailed introduction to MaTeX.

I tried :

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
"pdfLaTeX" -> "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\tex\\latex\\00miktex\\pdflatex.ini",
"Ghostscript" -> "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.20\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"
]
```

but there is an error message

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]

MaTeX["x^2"]
```

[image]

How can I configure the path to the "pdflatex" and "Ghostscript" executables manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I configure the path to the "pdflatex" and "Ghostscript" **executables** manually?

`pdflatex.ini` is not an *executable*. Use `pdflatex.exe`.